# JuJu LXD and Docker

Tags: juju, docker, lxd

What is the main difference in using LXD with respect to Docker containers with JuJu Charms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LXD hosts virtual machine containers (ie: VM), and Docker hosts app containers.